# Laravel returns when using view('page')->withErrors($v->errors()); but not with redirect()->back()->withErrors($v->errors())

Tags: laravel, redirect, view

I think title shows what the problem is. I want to send the errors with

```
return redirect()->back()->withErrors($v->errors());
```

but in view I can't even dd, print_r, var_dump it!
but when I use

```
return view('page')->withErrors($v->errors());
```

it works fine and I could print errors correctly!

Help me!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your routes are within web middleware.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::resource('AdminController');
});
```

If session is not started for the rout using session start middle ware `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,` errors and form values won't be returned.

Comment: Thank you very much dear George :)